# using explode inside a for loop and creating variables in php

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array

This is my URL:

```
http://example.com/shop-login.php?currency=USD&shipping=9.12&itemCount=2&item_name_1=+2014+New+Arriva+EGO+1500mAh+Big+Vape+HaKa+Twist+Variable+Voltage+Electronic+Cigarette+Battery+-+3+Optional+Colors&item_quantity_1=1&item_price_1=23.52&item_options_1=color%3A+Color%2C+pid%3A+5&item_name_2=+2014+hot+sell+2200mah+ego+Electronic+Cigarette+Battery+with+kgo+1+week+big+capacity+-+8+Optional+Colors&item_quantity_2=1&item_price_2=13&item_options_2=color%3A+Black%2C+pid%3A+6&Shipping_Option=EMS-Express
```

and php code as follows:

```
$item_count = (int) $_GET['itemCount'];
$i = 1;
$subtotal = (int) 0.00;
$grandtotal = (int) 0.00;
$items = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $item_count; $i++) {
    $items[$i]['name'] = $_GET["item_name_".$i];
    echo "item_name_".$i .'='. $items[$i]['name'] .'<br />' ;
    $items[$i]['quantity'] = $_GET["item_quantity_".$i];
    echo $items[$i]['quantity'] .'<br />' ;
    $items[$i]['price'] = $_GET["item_price_".$i];
    echo $items[$i]['price'] .'<br />' ;

    $items[$i]['options'] = $_GET["item_options_".$i];

    echo $items[$i]['options'] .'<br />' ;
    //$item1 = explode (',', $items[$i]['options']);
    //print_r($item1);  
    $subtotal += ($items[$i]['quantity'] * $items[$i]['price']);
    $grandtotal = ($subtotal + $shipping_cost);
```

I have the `$items[$i]['options']` having values like:

> color: Yellow, pid: 5

and

> color: Black, pid: 6

inside the for loop for 2 products.

I need to make color and pid as two separate variables inside the for loop. 
The value separator is , and i tried using explode.

I am confused as to how to obtain the variables inside `$items[$i]['options']` as separate variables inside the loop. For some products there will be more variables like flavor, size etc.

How to obtain the color,pid or other values like flavor, size etc as separate variables for each product id. ex: `color_1, pid_1, size_1` etc..etc

**Update:**
I got this working as follows:

```
$itemexp1 = explode (",", $items[$i]['options']);
foreach ($itemexp1 as $key => $dat){
$pid[$key] = explode(":", $dat);  
}
```

Comment: The first thing I could ask - why you send so much data in url? You should probably use `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` and not `$_GET`

Comment: Explode 2 times. First on a comma then on a `:`

Comment: @Marcin Nabiałek I am using POSt...For testing i am using GET. But unfortunately that was not my question ??

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky When i explode once the result will be an array. explode expects string ??

Comment: Try using `explode()` on `,` and see what you'll get. Probably `{color: Black}, {pid: 6}` on second example. Then use `explode()` again on `:` and you'll end up with `{color}, {black}, {pid}, {6}`. Then just grab the ones you want.

Comment: @user3790186, well then make it into a `string`. Grab the indexes you want and use `explode()` on them.

Comment: Please, read the rules before posting. Minimum Working Example aka MWE is like only 2 variables query (1 working and 1 color + pid string) and few lines of PHP code. BTW, creating MWE is enough to understand it yourself quite often. 
tl;dr: make MWE, make sure it fails, not "here is bootload of code, pls understand it for me"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$items = $items[$i]['options'];

$firstArray = explode(",", $items[0]);
$secondArray = explode(":", $firstArray[0]);
$color = $secondArray[1];

$firstArray = explode(",", $items[0]);
$secondArray = explode(":", $firstArray[1]);
$pId = $secondArray[1];

echo $color . " " . $pId;
```

Comment: $color = $secondArray[1];

$pid = $thirdArray[1];    Error Undefined offset: 1 in